# Namespace prefix missing on Soap Request via Web Reference

Tags: vb.net, soap

Here is my setup, i have a WSDL File which i imported into my App and it created the References which i can call to make my request. All is fine except the request are missing the prefix for the name spaces.
My request looks like this (captured via SoapUI)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/preorder">
     <ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
        <HDR>
           <MSG_TIMESTAMP>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MSG_TIMESTAMP>
           <CC>30H</CC>
           <STATE>CA</STATE>
        </HDR>
        <PON>TESTPON</PON>
     </ADDR_VAL_REQ>
  </ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the remote system expects something like this, ns1 and ns2 is just a samlpe prefix could be anything

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <ns1:ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns:ns1="http://lsr.att.com/preorder">
     <ns2:ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns:ns2="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
        <ns2:HDR>
           <ns2:MSG_TIMESTAMP>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ns2:MSG_TIMESTAMP>
           <ns2:CC>30H</ns2:CC>
           <ns2:STATE>CA</ns2:STATE>
        </ns2:HDR>
        <ns2:PON>TESTPON</ns2:PON>
     </ns2:ADDR_VAL_REQ>
  </ns1:ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Also just for reference here is what the ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ looks like

```
Partial Public Class ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ

    Private aDDR_VAL_REQField As ADDR_VAL_REQ

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM")>  _
    Public Property ADDR_VAL_REQ() As ADDR_VAL_REQ
        Get
            Return Me.aDDR_VAL_REQField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.aDDR_VAL_REQField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

So i am wondering is there any  place i can set the system to use namespace prefixes ?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample of

```
<ns1:ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/preorder">
  <ns2:ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
```

is not valid XML document since ns1 and ns2 are not defined. It souhld look like this when using prefixes

```
<ns1:ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns:ns1="http://lsr.att.com/preorder">
  <ns2:ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns:ns2="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
```

but the meaning is completely the same as

```
<ATT_ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/preorder">
   <ADDR_VAL_REQ xmlns="http://lsr.att.com/obf/tML/UOM">
```

so the request should pass on server side.

You can't affect using prefixes by config or attributes I believe. It would require writing own serializer or some IEndpointBehavior + IClientMessageInspector to modify the output.

Comment: Yes your right i missed that one, just did a basic edit to show the namespace issue.(i update sample) . So where can i find some more info on how to go about doing this via IEndpointBehavoir and IClientMessageInspector ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client but it's not a good idea. Try to use WireShark to see what's really going on on the wire.